# Azure login to multi-tenant AD app failing

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have user A in tenant A and a multi-tenant AD app B in tenant B. I am trying to get token from user A's context for the AD app

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=a573ddda-b34a-4206-a73b-d67ff6e98aec&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&scope=a573ddda-b34a-4206-a73b-d67ff6e98aec%2F.default&response_mode=fragment&state=12345&nonce=678910

I logged in using user A's credentials and got error

```
AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'a573ddda-b34a-4206-a73b-d67ff6e98aec' was not found in the directory 'domainA.onmicrosoft.com'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.
```

I have configured AD app B with id - a573ddda-b34a-4206-a73b-d67ff6e98aec to be multi-tenant. Any idea why this might not be working?

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. What kind of scopes does the app require? And what are the users' home tenants?

Comment: I'm trying to get tokem for default scope "/.default". I did not understand your second question. The user A's tenant is just a dofferent tenant. Should that matter as AD app B is a multi tenant app?

Comment: Default scope for what API? Typically you specify an API's id + /.default to use the statically defined permissions. The reason I'm asking about the user's home tenant is that if user A was a guest user in tenant A, the common endpoint would not be signing them in to tenant A, but rather to their home tenant. That can create issues sometimes, though it might not be what is going on here.

Comment: I did add user A as a guest user in tenant A. I actually did not find much documentation on the difference between a guest user and a regular user. Could you point me to some doc?
The scope is the app's default scope -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-v1-app-scopes#scopes-to-request-access-to-all-the-permissions-of-a-v10-application

Comment: Could you try testing something by changing your app's authority to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-a-id/v2.0` instead of `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0`? This would force the user signing in to authenticate against tenant A instead of their home tenant.

Comment: @user3740951,please share  the end points of your tenant which will be available in App Registration->overview->endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @juunas mentioned, if you use a guest user to login, use the `tenant id` of the tenant A instead of `common`, it will force the user to authenticate against tenant A  instead of his home tenant.

And if your guest user is the first login the app, make sure some settings are like below in tenant A, otherwise, the user will not be able to consent for the app in tenant A.

1. Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in tenant A -> `User settings` -> `Manage external collaboration settings` -> set `Guest users permissions are limited` to `No`.

[image]

2. Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in tenant A -> `Enterprise applications` -> `User settings` -> set `Users can consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf` to `Yes`.

[image]

For more details about the member user and guest user, see this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions

Comment: Hi Joy. Would you be able to help me answer this question? I can't seem to understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error caused by completely different factors:
I configured the Oauth2 client using **Secret ID** and Secret Value instead of **App ID** and Secret Value.

It took few hours browsing tons of config pages to figure out that the reason is stupidly simple and responses from MS API are useless.

Comment: OMG Thank you so much! I was going in circles.